# Does this fall under 2D Animation or 3D Animation?

Tags: 3d, animation, adobe-animate

I have been searching hard for past few weeks and not been able to find even single video on youtube, etc. which can show how to create a video like this. I am not sure if this is done in Adobe Animate  Character Animate or if thats done in 3D software like Max or Blender.

What I have seen the the characters in usual 2D animation don't have that much detail, but these videos look like the real character. And not even one character the whole video look like the 2D version of some 3D video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2P2Co8tpcyw&t=128s

> [image]
> [image]

Can anyone please help me on this to find which software was used to create this?

You can see in this image the cars look like 3d.

[image]

Comment: @user287001 you said as side product in 3d. Which 3d software in  your view should be able to produce that type of video . I have to start from scratch so rather than wasting time 2D , i can start with 3d

Answer (score 3):

Impossible to be definitive. Contact the creator for a definitive answer.

To me, it *looks like* 2D drawings which are then animated. The animation itself consists of *simple* position tweening. It's not altering the objects themselves. It's merely repositioning the objects. Sure the cars *look* like pseudo-3D but that's just their appearance. They appear to be drawn in 2D software utilizing some perspective to give a sense of depth, that's all.

No different than drawing a box in a 2D app and making it *look* like it has depth....

[image]

If it were 3D animation then the scale and perspective of objects would be changing as they are animated. That's not happening in the video.

As for what was used to create this... well all I can do is **guess**. I'd say they are 2D vector drawings (Inkscape, Illustrator, Xara, CorelDraw) then moved to some animation software (Animate, After Effects, Premier, Final Cut, iMovie).

What you use to create either the vector drawing or animation is up to you. Simply using the *same* tools won't ever get you the *same* results. Typically it's more about the *nature* of the tools, i.e. vector based v raster based, than what *specific* tool may have been used.

Can you create something like the cars in Photoshop and then animate them? Sure you can. But it's just easier in a vector app and a dedicated animation app.

Comment: Thanks . I am very beginner  and my target is to create videos like that video and  so from your expereince for that type of video i  first need to master the vector drawing in Illustrator example and then  animate them using any tool like Animate or After effects? or u think doing everything in 3D software will be easier ?

Comment: Everyone has different levels of aptitude. I can't tell you what would be "easier" for you.

Comment: Sorry i will frame other way , If i learn 3d software like Blender , will be able to create video like those with  toonish effect . I dont want  them to look real 3ds but like in above image ?

Comment: I can not answer what you will or will not be able to do. I have no clue as to your skill levels, aptitude for learning, or creativity. It it possible in Blender or Illustrator? Sure. Will you be able to do that? I have no idea.

Comment: Just one last question. Suppose if you have to create video exactly like that (Just imagine for moment) what tools/softwares you will use. Example illustrator for drwing objects like cars ,  human etc and then Animate for animation or you will create 3D  models of  cars, Human in Blender and then animate in Blender itself

Comment: It doesn't matter what I would use, I'm not the one needing to learn software. What I would suggest if you know nothing.. is to start learning *something* and see how it goes. If you are picking things up quickly, then continue. If you are merely struggling with everything then perhaps try a different tool. Things like that video can take **years** to learn how to do well.... no answer here will be a "fast track" to any type of completed, polished, project in a few weeks or even perhaps months.

Comment: @kgill - also note that video editing is off topic here. Your questions might be more suitable for Blender Stack Exchange, or even Video Production Stack Exchange.

Comment: @kgill consider that animation, even simple one as this has a market value of about 50 dollars per second of output + the costs of assets. In general unless you are a teenager or at minimum a student. Then you dont have the time to learn a 3D application it takes about 6months -1 year of full time dedication to get there if its even enough. Our uni teaches a full year course 4 hours a week, and the dropout rate is astonishing. Out of 30-45 people about 2-5 are left standing at the end of the course. Allmost always those people had piror experience in animation.

Comment: The amount of dedication needed is quite high. Not saying one cant make it but be prepared to work more than you ever have

Answer (score 1):

Everything shown in your example can be made by moving in a multitrack video editor flat 2D items which are layered. One car is also scaled during its motion, but none of the moving items change it's viewing angle nor perspective. These things would happen nearly automatically - as side products - in 3D because 3D models can be rotated to any possible view with no extra effort. But smoothly rotating views need an astronomical effort in 2D animations.

I'm not claiming it's impossible. See for ex. movie Bambi. The Disney army crafted it 5 years before it was published in 1942. Even its opening scene is a light year ahead what we can see made today. A common compromise is to let 1...2 center characters to rotate to different views and everything else is kept flat.

In a comment you asked "Which 3d software should be able to produce that type of video?"

The answer: None. Video is made by a person or an organized group. Software is only a tool. Try at first construct a 2D video to see what the job takes. Blender surely has everything you need to create a video in 3D scene, but learning enough of Blender functions takes time, even years. You may put together a rotating cube or bottle in a day by following tutorials, but an interesting video is totally different. A parable: Purchasing the finest available woodworking tools do not make me a respected furniture carpenter - not even if I could imagine nice looking furnitures in details. But that imagination capability would be a perfect starting point.

Creating the 2D images of the cars shown in your example needs a skilled draughtsman. Right forms and glosses do not come out without a heavy practicing to draw. A beginner cannot expect to draw from scratch anything as good only after a few days, it takes an year to develop any confidence and it needs talent, too. Putting enough details into a 3D model is at least as challenging, but then one gets all possible views with zero extra effort.

I see creating a video as a higher level task than creating the shapes in the video. A person making videos may purchase the needed complex shapes and do his creative work by making them to move in a good order. Separating the levels - that's how complex tasks are generally managed in human life.

If I had those already well drawn 2D car images of your example, putting together as plausible video wouldn't be a big deal in any multitrack video editor. I could well draw the rest of the items by myself and move the cars in layers with keyframe animation (including the rotating wheels). You will believe it after you put some simple shapes to move in a video editor.

If one day some obscure reason forced me to make a resembling video I would try at first download some free well drawn cars. Or some free 3D models and render from them the wanted views of the cars for a simple 2D animation.

Realistic cars:

You may have seen in television how Chip Foose or Dave Kindig draw realistic cars (as well existing ones as their own models). Or this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-T6Z4dZUMtE.

I guess very few of us can make the same, but I think it's perfectly useless to imagine that software makes it for you if you cannot put anything at least a little resembling onto paper with a pen. It's not only the technical ability to draw, but also the ability to imagine every detail with its relations to other details.

Start from something simple and move to tougher tasks gradually. If you have got what's needed for the job, something worth of showing appears after few thousand drawings.

Comment: Thank you very much man , i have started learing Adobe Animate now but i will surely reach that level even if it takes years. i am not going to give up